# Class and member destructors called twice

Tags: c++, explicit-destructor-call

```
class A
{
public:
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "A destroyed" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    A a;
    ~B()
    {
        std::cout << "B destroyed" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.~B();
}
```

Output:

```
B destroyed
A destroyed
B destroyed
A destroyed
```

Can someone explain to me what's going on here? I expected the output to be

```
B destroyed
A destroyed
```

(once when ~B() is called and once ~A() is called).

Comment: This is called "undefined behaviour". Just read the warning sections where it explains the syntax of explicit destructor invocations.

Comment: Why are you doing an explicit destructor call in that code?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oh i didn't know we aren't supposed to call the destructor explicitly.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Ok I see. Thanks.

Comment: @Jamāl I hope that my answer will help you understand **why** you don't need to call the destructor.

Comment: The only time you need to explicitly call the destructor is when you've used placement new to construct the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any object that was created in a limited scope would be destroyed when the scope is exited.
Meaning, that if you have created an object ***on the stack***, it will be destroyed when the stack will fold back, along with any other variables declared in that scope.

The only exception to this is when you are using dynamic allocation of objects, using the keyword `new`, this creates the object on ***the heap***, which doesn't clean itself on its own. But even then, calling `delete` will invoke the destructor on its own.

Having said that, in order to avoid using `new` and `delete`, and for better resource management, there are types (such as smart-pointers) that handle these on their own, in a technique called Resource Allocation Is Initialization (or [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)), which makes things much simpler (and you get to the first part, all is allocated on the stack, thus the destructors are being called automatically when it folds).